# Kodak ESP Aio prints good on Ubuntu 12.04, butnothing finds the scanner. Any ideas, please?

Tags: scanner, kodak

My Kodak ESP 3250 prints great on Ubuntu 12.04, but nothing finds the scanner. Tried xsane and Libre Writer to no avail. Need all the help I can get. Only other printers I have to use are, ugh, Lexmarks.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

just spent some time poking around, starting to git clone the "sane backends" and then wondered if they were already present...hooray,it seems in 12.04 quantal the sane backends are already there. I was able to find my scanner's conf file in /etc/sane.d/
I specifically have a Kodak AiO ESP5250
I did need to open & edit the kodakaio.conf file

FIRST even tho it said autodetect for network was enabled, i needed to uncomment the line for my ESP5250 network connection

and
SECOND i also needed to change my ip address to reflect what my printer said on its little control panel (under "network settings"->"view network configuration"->IP address) my scanner said 192.168.1.7, instead of the prepopulated/default of 192.169.1.4 that was there

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

[Here are instructions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cupsdriverkodak/files/Scanning%20-%20sane%20backend/) for installing Kodak Aio sane backends on Sourceforge.net. If you follow the instructions closely you should be fine.

Comment: @Frank249942 Did those instructions work out for you?